# How to get rid off extra decimals

Tags: javascript

I have a response which is sending me a value of 0.0554

And the following is my code to convert it into a percentage and display it.

```
  var m_e = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).moe;
  console.log(m_e); //here I am getting 0.0554
  var e = m_e*100;
  console.log(e); //here I am getting 5.539999999999999
  $('#element').html('&plusmn;' + e + '%');
```

And as a result I am getting this enormous value. But I want to print 5.54 only.

Where am I going wrong?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use `toFixed` - `e.toFixed(2)`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks!

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal It takes time to find duplicates - which you could also have done yourself!!

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I don't have to argue or answer your petty questions. Instead why don't you gimme one good reason why didn't you searched for a dupe for this one, which has been answered at least thousand times!!

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal And you still haven't removed your answer even after seeing that attached link is linked to 81 such duplicates!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1726630?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed(2)` to get two digits after the decimal point:

```js
var data = {
  "moe" : 0.0554
}

var m_e = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).moe;
  console.log(m_e); 
  var e = m_e*100;
  console.log(e); 
  $('#element').html('&plusmn;' + e.toFixed(2) + '%');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='element'></span>
```